# Unwrap string before attaching it to the document

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

I wrote the following code to append a new table row to my `#displayResult` table with the data I receive from my `#getInfo` form when it is submitted.

I was asked to implement a WYSIWYG HTML editor in my textarea ([jHtmlArea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/)) so that users can add basic styling to their comments. It simply wraps the targeted content in `<b/>` or `<i/>` tags, for example.

In my table, only **previews** of the actual comments are displayed (limited to 40 characters) and I use PHP's `strip_tags()` to make sure no styling/unwanted tags appear in the displayed preview when the page has been refreshed.

In a nutshell, I'd like to apply the same treatment on my AJAX response so I'm basically looking for a JS way to emulate `strip_tags()` in this context.

My question is : how can I unwrap the comment and clear it from all the `<b/>` or `<i/>` tags **before** it is appended? Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

```
$('#getInfo').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var company = $('select#company').val();
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    var comment = $('textarea#comment').val();
    comment = comment.substring(0,40);
    comment = comment + '...'; 

    var dataString = [company, name, comment];
    var n = dataString.length;

    var row = $('<tr class="temp">');       

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../process.php',
        data: $('#getInfo').serialize(),
        success: function() {

            for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                row
                    .append($('<td>')
                    .html(dataString[i]))
            }

            $(row).appendTo('#displayResult').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a jQuery object with the response and then get the text as follows:

```
var theString = dataString[i];
var strippedString = $(theString).text();
```

This will basically create a new jQuery object, parsing any tags wrapping the response. Then using the `.text()` method will get only the text, ignoring those tags.

// EDIT

In response to the query about where the above lines would be placed... I would suggest using them as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var theString = dataString[i];
    var strippedString = $(theString).text();
    row
        .append($('<td>')
        .html(strippedString))
    }
```

This modifies the code you already have to instead insert the stripped text into each row of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I tried that already and it generates an empty row. It seems to be messing with the loop.

Comment: try using row.append($('<td>'+strippedString+'</td>') instead maybe? Manipulating the string like that shouldn't be messing with the loop